# Как менять компонент с анимацией?

Tags: reactjs

Есть два компонента (A, B) я хочу скажем при клике на кнопку в компоненте A сменить его на B или на оборот. Но, хочу не просто его поменять, а хочу поменять его с анимацией по типу бокового меню, когда оно с левой/правой части вылетает. Для более наглядного примера: вот когда мы в телеграмме нажимаем на какуе-то переписку, то у нас меняется компонент с анимацией. Вот как такое сделать?

Comment: Как вариант... Сначала скрываешь анимировано элемент `A`. Меняешь его на скрытый элемент `B`. Анимировано показываешь его.

Comment: Лучший ответ года [кринж]

Comment: Да как скажешь...